# Unable to create an Installble trigger on a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, triggers, google-forms

I've created a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) which takes a spreadsheet id, a trello's list id, trello api key and a user's trello token as input.

Upon getting the input, the Google app script creates an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) on the spreadsheet such that the trigger will get executed whenever someone submits the google form linked with the spreadsheet and creates a trello card in the specified trello list.

Initially I tested this script by creating a google form (and hence a google sheet) and by giving the script the required input mentioned above. This worked completely fine, the script was successfully able to create a trigger on the specified spreadsheet.

The problem was that the google form and the google app script project were both linked to my Google account and hence there was no trouble for me to access my own resources programmatically. As soon as I tried to create a trigger on a sheet that was of some other user I was not allowed to do so.

I had published this script as webapp with execute app permission as **Me** and anonymous access to the app.

[image: Permission settings for the script]

I used Postman to make the api calls to the script and when submitting the input required to create the trigger I'm getting an HTML that says this:

[image]

I also tried to change the execution permissions to this:

[image]

But then got this response:

[image]

I'm assuming that I'll need to get permission from the user to be able to set a trigger on his/her resource but I'm not sure how to achieve that any suggestions would be appreciated.

Just for the sake of completeness, here is the code to set up a trigger on a spreadsheet.

```
function getTrigger(data){

    return ScriptApp.newTrigger("createTrelloCard").forSpreadsheet(data["spreadsheet_key"])
        .onFormSubmit()
        .create();
}
```

Comment: This isn't answer to your question but you should insure that there isn't a trigger with that name before creating and second one.  Other wise your going to get multiple triggers.

Comment: So the user of your webapp has to have access the spreadsheet in order to create the trigger.  I would make this webapp standalone and deploy it to run as user and let anyone access it and of course they will have to authorize when the first use it.

Comment: Hey @Cooper, the script is already deployed as a standalone webapp which runs as a user and anyone can have access, I'm not sure how to ask for authorization when the first use it.

Comment: If you set the execute the script as "User accessing the web app" then they need to have access to all the resources listed by the script. Are you setting the trigger every time the webapp is invoked? Is that is the case then you have a problem there. Why do you mean with input as WebApp? Why are you using the WebApp for?

Comment: A sequence diagram for each of your attempts would help clarify who's calling what. What fails on line 29 is it the creation of the trigger? or the call on the trigger? Perhaps you should expand the spreadsheet gs manifest to include trigger creation?